# Save more than one pdf page

Tags: objective-c, pdf

i am saving a pdf file from url and if i save a single page then there is no problem but when i save the whole pdf app is getting crashed without any logs

my code

```
CGPDFDocumentRef document = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)url);
NSString *pass = [_JSON objectForKey:@"pass"];
CGPDFDocumentUnlockWithPassword(document, [pass UTF8String]);

int i = (int) CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(document);
NSLog(@"Number Of pages: %d",i);


//Create the pdf context
for (int j = 0; j<i; j++) {
    page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(document, j+1); //Pages are numbered starting at 1
    pageRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page, kCGPDFMediaBox);
    mutableData = CFDataCreateMutable(NULL, j);
}

//NSLog(@"w:%2.2f, h:%2.2f",pageRect.size.width, pageRect.size.height);
CGDataConsumerRef dataConsumer = CGDataConsumerCreateWithCFData(mutableData);
CGContextRef pdfContext = CGPDFContextCreate(dataConsumer, &pageRect, NULL);

if (CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(document) > 0)
{
    //Draw the page onto the new context
    //page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(document, 1); //Pages are numbered starting at 1

    CGPDFContextBeginPage(pdfContext, NULL);
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(pdfContext, page);
    CGPDFContextEndPage(pdfContext);
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to create the document");
}

CGContextRelease(pdfContext); //Release before writing data to disk.

//Write to disk
[(__bridge NSData *)mutableData writeToFile:@"/Users/user/Desktop/sample.pdf" atomically:YES];

//CleanUP
CGDataConsumerRelease(dataConsumer);
CGPDFDocumentRelease(document);
CFRelease(mutableData);
```

i think the problem is with the loop but don't know much about this module i am trying this for the first time.
[Here is the output log which i could never understand and there is no log in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEHFt.png)

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer myself by fiddling with my code 
here is my new working coding

```
CGPDFDocumentRef document = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)url);
NSString *pass = [_JSON objectForKey:@"pass"];
CGPDFDocumentUnlockWithPassword(document, [pass UTF8String]);

int i = (int) CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(document);
NSLog(@"Number Of pages: %d",i);

//Create the pdf context
CGPDFPageRef page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(document, 1); //Pages are numbered starting at 1
CGRect pageRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page, kCGPDFMediaBox);
CFMutableDataRef mutableData = CFDataCreateMutable(NULL, 0);


CGDataConsumerRef dataConsumer = CGDataConsumerCreateWithCFData(mutableData);
CGContextRef pdfContext = CGPDFContextCreate(dataConsumer, &pageRect, NULL);

if (CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(document) > 0)
{
    //Draw the page onto the new context
    //page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(document, 1); //Pages are numbered starting at 1

    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(document, j+1);
    CGPDFContextBeginPage(pdfContext, NULL);
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(pdfContext, page);
    CGPDFContextEndPage(pdfContext);
    }
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to create the document");
}
CGContextRelease(pdfContext); //Release before writing data to disk.

//Write to disk

NSArray *arr = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
path = arr[0];
path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sample.pdf"];

[(__bridge NSData *)mutableData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];


//CleanUP
CGDataConsumerRelease(dataConsumer);
CGPDFDocumentRelease(document);
CFRelease(mutableData);
```

i was just looping the whole thing where as i should be looping only the part i was doing the page creation part.